# How to show logout link in drupal

Tags: 7

I have created a user account. Then signed out of admin and logged in with the new user account. But the new account does not have a logout link, So how can i show it to the other users ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a link to `user/logout`. It can be a menu item or an HTML link in a block.

Answer (score 2):

The logout link is included in the user menu that is standard to drupal.

Make sure the equivalent user menu block is active in an appropriate region and you will have your logout link

Answer (score 1):

Step by step instructions:

In the view that you want to add 'logout' link

1. Add new field
2. Select 'Global: Custom Text'
3. Uncheck 'Create a label'
4. In textarea put: 'Logout'
5. Click 'Rewrite Results'
6. Check 'Output this field as a link'
7. Link path: 'user/logout'
8. Save

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to follow the following Steps:
--Login with Admin
--Go to the option of People
--Now you have to click on "permissions" option 
--Here a list of various permissions is open 
--Now search "Toolbar" where you have to tick on the option of "Use the administration toolbar" for authenticated user
--Just save it and it done.